# How to connect Infinity Free database to Fast API

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, fastapi, pymysql

```
How to connect Infinity Free  database to Fast API ?
While connecting database by using below code:
---------------------------------------------
conn = pymysql.connect(host="sql108.infinityfree.com",
port=3306,
user="myuser",
password="password",
db="mydatabase",
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

### getting below error:

"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql108.infinityfree.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"

Comment: (1) This looks like a DNS or network issue, unless you have misspelt the name of the server (2) You should change your password - use dummy credentials when asking questions here.